# Is the chi squared test appropriate?

Tags: chi-squared-test

I have claim data from two different insurance administrators. From each administrator, I have calculated the relativity of miles driven per year based on claim data. I want to determine whether combining the data is appropriate based on whether the distribution of driving behavior between the two administrators is "similar". Can I use a Pearson's chi-squared test of independence on the relativity from each administrator.

EDIT:

```
 [1] 0.002506266 0.004010025 0.001503759 0.005012531 0.012531328 0.009523810 0.018546366
 [8] 0.031578947 0.040601504 0.047117794 0.075187970 0.070175439 0.082205514 0.086215539
[15] 0.089724311 0.061152882 0.064160401 0.067669173 0.045614035 0.040601504 0.027067669
[22] 0.024060150 0.013533835 0.013533835 0.010025063 0.011528822 0.005513784 0.011027569
[29] 0.006516291 0.005012531 0.003007519 0.003508772 0.002005013 0.001002506 0.001503759
[36] 0.001002506 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.001503759 0.000501253 0.000000000
[43] 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.002506266 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000
[50] 0.000000000
```

Comment: Can you tell us a little more about "relativity of miles driven per year" what kind of values does it take? What is a typical distribution of those values?

Comment: What do the numbers represent in relation to your question? Is that miles driven per year for one administrator? for both? Something else?

Comment: .2506% of drivers drove less than 1000 mpy, .4010% drive between 1000 and 2000 mpy, etc. This is the data for a single administrator.